# Safari - automatically add preventDefault if <a> has on click event?

Tags: html, safari

I have this button that will open `page-a` in new tab while the current page will move to `page-b`

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/page-a/" target="_blank" onclick="goToPageB()">Click me</a>
```

It works fine in Chrome but in Safari, it goes to `page-b` while ignoring the url in `href`.

So my guess is: Safari automatically add `preventDefault()` if the anchor tag has `click` event?

Is there solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried an explicit `return true` in the onclick?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. I changed to `onclick="goToPageB(); return true;"` but still doesn't work. Am I doing it wrong?